# Aws Push notification stops after sometime and works starts restarting tomcat

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am facing some weird issue in AWS Push notification . I have implemented it with Spring Boot, it works fine but after sometime it stops working by itself, i don't see any logs as well. But when i start my tomcat again it start working. Can someone help me out?

Comment: In your CloudWatch, Under Log Groups, your application's delivery status logs has any Failed Delivery Reports? Also, are you using Tomcat 7 ?

Comment: no reports, using tomcat 9